# Как сохранить порядок TabPage (вкладок)

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. 
Ситуация следующая: создается определенное кол-во TabPage(вкладок) динамически. В результате получается определенное кол-во рядов.
Проблема: при выборе вкладки весь ряд, содержащий эту вкладку, перемещается в первый ряд.
Вопрос: что нужно сделать, чтобы порядок вкладок не менялся?

Пример:

Page1; Page2; Page3:

Page4; Page4; Page5

после выбора Page2:

Page4; Page4; Page5

Page1; Page2; Page3

Comment: для хранения настроек приложения используйте [Properties.Settings][1]


  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы используете WinForms, то компонент по умолчанию, по-моему, такого не позволяет, эта "фишка" уже давно. Попробуйте пошариться в его свойствах. Да и зачем Вам сделать так, чтобы порядок вкладок не менялся? Какую цель Вы преследуете?

Comment: Да вот шарюсь, пока безрезультатно. Цель следующая, у меня более 100 вкладок пронумерованных. В ряд помещатся 11, итого более 10 рядов. При выборе разных вкладок, порядок рядов постоянно менятеся, а это ооочень не удобно для работы и поиска нужной.

Comment: Сделайте спец. панельку для поиска нужного таба: текстовое поле для поиска по имени и кнопка ОК, которая активирует нужный таб. панельку можно скрыть в случае чего.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но это не совсем то, что нужно. Дело в том, что имена табов - "Имя - номер". То есть не информативно. Пользователю такой поиск не удобен.

Comment: у таба есть заголовок. (к слову, можно искать по заголовкам. заголовок (Title\Caption) и имя таба(Name\ID) - разные вещи). В принципе, можно даже добавить выпадающий список, чтоб красиво было и отображать там заголовки табов.

Comment: Список - вариант. Если не найду решение проблемы, то попробую со списком. Спасибо.